# Override property of custom style

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, properties

I have Style that applies to all of the buttons of my application:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="AliceBlue" Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Ellipse.Width>
                            <Binding ElementName="StatusButtonCircle" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        </Ellipse.Width>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Margin="4" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Uniform">
                        <Ellipse.Width>
                            <Binding ElementName="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        </Ellipse.Width>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ... some Triggers here
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How can I change properties (e.g. FontWeight, FontSize etc.) in XAML? I tried this:

```
<Button FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="30" Foreground="Red">
</Button>
```

In the designer-view, I see the changes. But during runtime those changes are not applied.

---

After some investigation, I also have a Style for all TextBlock like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
</Style>
```

This Style seems to override the TextBlock that is used on the Button. I still can't change the Text Properties in XAML.

Here's what it looks like if I use the Styles above in an empty project:

[image]

In the designer, the changes are applied, during runtime the one from the TextBlock are applied. If I assign a x:Key to the TextBlock, it works fine. But then I have to assign this Style to every TextBlock used in the app manually.

Comment: The code you provided does not reproduce the issue. I just created new project, added Button and TextBlock styles to resources, added the Button element, and it works (foreground is Red). Try creating a test project where you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: BasedOn should point to another "base" style for Button, it is not used to specify the target type.

Comment: @Fredrik It can be used like that when you want to extend global style for the type - [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/styling-and-templating#extending-styles).

Comment: @djomlastic true. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing  typical style inheritance issue in wpf.

A control looks for its style at the point when it is being initalized. The way the controls look for their style is by moving upwards in logical tree and asking the logical parent if there is appropriate style for them stored in parent's resources dictionary.

In your case, you are using ContentPresenter in button as a default behaviour. and it is using TextBlock to represent text in button by default.

Therefore at the time of initialization, ContentPresenter finding TextBlock style and applying to represent content in button.

If you want to restrict ContentPresenter to look for the style then you have to bind a blank style to content presenter so that it will not look for any further style.

```
<Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircle" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="AliceBlue" Stretch="Uniform">
                                <Ellipse.Width>
                                    <Binding ElementName="StatusButtonCircle" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                </Ellipse.Width>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Margin="4" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Stretch="Uniform">
                                <Ellipse.Width>
                                    <Binding ElementName="StatusButtonCircleHighlight" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                                </Ellipse.Width>
                            </Ellipse>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{x:Null}"/>
                                    <!--  Assigned Blank style here therefore it will not search for any further style-->
                                </ContentPresenter.Resources>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Grid>


                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `BasedOn`. I show you an example.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefToggleButton}">
       <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
       <Setter Property="Content" Value="Some Cool Stuff"/>
           <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Content" Value="More Stuff"/>
                </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Here in my resources I have DefToggleButton, now in my xaml file I can set up any `Property` according to my need (which in this case is the `FontWeight` and `Content` `Property`).

Answer (score 0):

I think if you remove the `Template` from your `Style`, then you can do what you want to do, like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="stBtn>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The `Template` that you have says, that all `Button`s should be shown as a `Border` with a `ContentPresenter` inside, which is not what you have asked.

Without the `Template`, you can define your `Button`s like this:

```
<Button Content="Hi!" Style="{StaticResource stBtn}" Foreground="Red" >
```

Like this, you have a Blue `Button` with Red Foreground.

=================

**Edit**

So what if you define a `Template`, and use it in you style, like this?

Then, by `TemplateBinding` you can define that the Foreground and teh Content come later, when the Button is actually defined.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ctBtn" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Label Background="Green" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="stBtn2" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template"
            Value="{StaticResource ctBtn}" />
    </Style> 
<Window.Resources>
```

Then by defining the `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Hi!" Style="{StaticResource stBtn2}" Foreground="Red" >
```

===============

**Edit2**

So the general idea is that you can define a TemplateBinding for the properties of the elements in your template. So for example,you have an Ellipse in your template:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
```

This defines that the Fill property of your Ellipse comes from the BorderBrush of your Button (Assuming that the template is targeting a Button)

Accordingly, you can put a `Label` in your `Template`, and set a `TemplateBinding` for its `Forground` and `FontWeight` property.

```
<Label Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
```

Comment: I simplified the style in my question. I do need the template, I added a Grid with ellipses etc.

Comment: @el-nino Edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry I saw the editted Template in your question later. So the general idea is that you can define a `TemplateBinding` for the properties of the elements in your template. So for example: you have an Ellipse in your template.  `<Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />` This defines that the `Fill` property of your Ellipse comes from the `BorderBrush` of your Button (Assuming that the template is targeting a Button)

Answer (score 0):

First, for this issue to be reproduced, `Style`s need to be set within a `ResourceDictionary` which is then added to `Application.Resources` (preciselly`TextBlock` global style). Setting `Style`s within for example `Window.Resources` will not reproduce the issue.

#### Global TextBlock Style is applied to the TextBlock created by ConentPresenter

As noticed in the question, the issue is that the global (keyless) `Style` for `TextBlock` is applied to the `TextBlock` created by `ContentPresenter` when it concludes the content to display is a string. For some reason this doesn't happen when that `Style` is defined within `Window.Resources`. As it turns out, there is more to this than just "controls are looking for their styles within their parent's resources".

#### ControlTemplate is a boundary for elements not deriving from Control class

For `TextBlock` (which doesn't derive from `Control` class, but from `UIElement`) within `ControlTemplate`, it means that wpf *will not look for it's implicit `Style` beyond* it's templated parent. So it won't look for implicit `Style` within it's parent's resources, it will apply application level implicit `Style` found within `Application.Resources`.

This is by design (hardcoded into `FrameworkElement` if you will), and *the reason is exactly to prevent issues like this one*. Let's say you're creating a specific `Button` design (as you are) and you want all buttons in your application to use that design, even buttons within other `ControlTemplate`s. Well, they can, as `Button` does derive from `Control`. On the other hand, you don't want all controls that use `TextBlock` to render text, to apply the implicit `TextBlock` `Style`. You will hit the same issue with `ComboBox`, `Label`... as they all use `TextBlock`, not just `Button`.

So the conclusion is: do not define global `Style` for elements which don't derive from `Control` class within `Application.Resources`, *unless you are 100% sure that is what you want* (move it to `Window.Resources` for example). Or, to quote a comment I found in source code for `MahApps.Metro` UI library: "never ever make a default Style for TextBlock in App.xaml!!!". You could use some solution to style the `TextBlock` within your `Button`'s `ControlTemplate`, but then you'll have to do it for `Label`, `ComboBox`, etc... So, just don't.